# Drupal Multisite in subfolders, www redirection in htaccess

Tags: drupal, .htaccess

I'm using a multisite setup in subfolders, everything works fine except the non-www to www redirection.

I got it working with no issues for the main domain, but I cant get it to work for the other sites: 
for example , I want this redirection :

site.com/ru > www.site.com/ru

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^site.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: This seems like a redirection for the main site, not the subsites, my goal is to redirect my subsite's urls. ex: site.com/fr/etc/etc should be redirected to www.site.com/fr/etc/etc

Comment: Just add new rules for each domain. If you are running any decent number of multisites try out Aegir, a site manager it will manage all this for you.

In my opinion www. is redundant, stackoverflow doesn't have it for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you check .htaccess file you may see on 85-90 line (Drupal 7.x):

```
# To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And if you uncomment this lines you may get solutions for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectPermanent /ru http://www.site.com/ru
```

might be a better alternative to Rewrite rules.